# make a GET call 100,000 times

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a requirement where I am writing a small utility to test apis(ofcourse there are existing tools but it has been decided to write one). I am required to bombard the api, for the same api call, with say 100 threads, around say 100,000 times.

I am using 'PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager' for the making the calls. I am using something as mentioned in the below link:

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

My question is:

(1) How can I run the above code for 100,000 iterations? Using that many number of threads is obviously a bad idea. Initially thought of using ExecutorService for maintaining thread count and number of jobs to be submitted but it felt redundant.

(2)I read about 'setMaxTotal'(max connections) and 'setDefaultMaxPerRoute'(concurrent connections) but I dont think it will help achieve(1) though I will obviously be required to increase the values.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'It has been decided'. Unless you tell why it has been decided not to just use jmeter, we aren't likely to give you useful advice as to what to do instead.

Comment: hmm, I did ask this, apparently the thought was to see if the application can handle these many queries without failure and not go into any any additional information. Sorry if the answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a threadpool and push the workerfunction the required number of times. Then you could even vary the number of workerthreads executing the functions to simulate different loadsituations.

Threadpool tutorial:
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did think of using ExecutorService as below: ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
          } But since I am already using "PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager" hence was not sure if it was required.

Comment: That's what makes programming so great. There is mostly an indefinite amount of possible solutions. There may be better or faster solutions but since I'm not experienced with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, I'd try a more generic approach. You surely could also find out if the Manager provides a solution for this case already.

Comment: Thank you Tomas. I am not experienced with 'PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager', hence I wanted opinions. Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Jmeter for such performance/load testing?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have replied in an earlier comment.

Comment: I second.  Don't reinvent a wheel, particularly when a "free" one is available

Comment: Sorry, I missed that comment. But if you are not comfortable with Jmeter, then go for curl commands or something equivalent like Apache bench. That will suffice your requirement. Also, as per my understanding, Executors in java is sufficient to handle multi threading.

Comment: Thanks Tasmine for your suggestions.